# kth smallest number in bst

Tags: recursion, binary-search-tree

I have the following code for finding the kth smallest number in a bst.

```
int kthsmallest(node* root, int* currentpos, int k){

    if(root->left != NULL){
            return kthsmallest(root->left, currentpos, k);
    }

    (*currentpos)++;
    if(*currentpos == k){
            return root->n;
    }

    if(root->right != NULL){
            return kthsmallest(root->right, currentpos, k);
    }

}
```

Caller (Assuming i have 10 numbers in the BST):

```
    int temp=0;
    for(i=1; i<10; i++){
            temp=0;
            printf("%d ", kthsmallest(root, &temp, i));
    }
```

This works fine till it has to print out the first few leaf nodes. However it does not give the correct answer for any other node after that. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Inorder traversal of BST prints out the BST in sorted manner. Push elements in a list as you traverse Inorder and then return the kth element of the list from the start.

Comment: Instead of pushing them in a list, i keep a count and when the count reaches k, i return the element. That is the supposed logic of the code above but something breaks there because of which it does not work.